# Zeros or minima of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, mathematical-optimization, numerical-value

what is the most reliable method for finding the zeros or at least the minimum of $f(x,y,z,w,r)= - \frac{3}{96 \pi^{2}z^{4}} \int_{y}^{\infty}\sqrt{x^{2}-y^{2}}x^{2} e^{-x} dx+ \frac{3}{16 \pi^{2}(1-r^{2})^{2} z^{4}}[1+ \frac{1}{3}[2- w^{2}+\frac{3-r^{2}}{1-r^{2}}] (1-r^{2})z^{2}+\frac{w^{2}}{6}(w^{2}-2)(1-r^{2})^{2} z^{4} ln(2(1-r^{2})z^{2})]$ using Mathematica ? here x,y,z,w and r are non-negative

Comment: In this forum, post the formula by Mathematica code is better than LaTeX.

Comment: Thnx! I will do it next time

Comment: @QuantumFields Please do it *this time* as well. You can always edit your own posts to add the code for this expression,

Comment: `f` is not a function of `x` since it is integrated out. You can avoid a complication if `y > 0` rather than `y >= 0`. To avoid a discontinuity either `-1 < r < 1` or `0 <= r <1`

Comment: r is larger or equal to 0 and less than 1 , I agree with you that the minimum is unbounded but when this expression equals to zero?

Comment: @Bill Thanks a lot ! I just want to discuss when this relation becomes zero when r is equal or greater than 0 but less than 1 and when z is free parameter and w is larger than y that what I want exactly to figure out using Mathematica if possible

Comment: @QuantumFields `y=0;r=0;Reduce[{-3/(96 Pi^2 z^4)Integrate[Sqrt[x^2-y^2]x^2 E^-x,{x,y,Infinity}]+ 3/(16 Pi^2(1-r^2)^2 z^4)(1+1/3(2-w^2+(3-r^2)/(1-r^2))(1-r^2)z^2+ w^2/6(w^2-2)(1-r^2)^2 z^4 Log[2(1-r^2)z^2])==0,z>=0&&w>y},{w,z}]` I do not think what you want to discuss or exactly figure out will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Get a graphical overview to see, the function has no minimum and is zero not at single points, but at a curve depending on parameters.

```
int = -3/(96 Pi^2 z^4) Integrate[
    Sqrt[x^2 - y^2] x^2 E^-x, {x, y, Infinity}, Assumptions -> y > 0]

rest = 3/(16 Pi^2 (1 - r^2)^2 z^4) (1 + 
 1/3 (2 - w^2 + (3 - r^2)/(1 - r^2)) (1 - r^2) z^2 + 
 w^2/6 (w^2 - 2) (1 - r^2)^2 z^4 Log[2 (1 - r^2) z^2]) // 
FullSimplify[#, 
Assumptions -> Join[{0 < r < 1}, Thread[{y, z, w} > 0]]] &

f2[y_, z_, w_, r_] = 
  int + rest // Together // 
 FullSimplify[#, 
Assumptions -> Join[{0 < r < 1}, Thread[{y, z, w} > 0]]] &

Manipulate[
  Plot3D[f2[y, z, w, r], {y, 0, 10}, {r, 0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {-100, 0}], {{z, 1/20}, 0, 9, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{w, 6}, 0, 20,  Appearance -> "Labeled"
}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable feedback!